# Use maskMoney in input that is created dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the form that opens by default the function in js works well.
But then in the form I have the possibility to create more fields dynamically, but in those fields that you create dynamically it doesn't work.

Let me explain.

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    var length = wrapper.find("input:text").length;

    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      
     $(wrapper).append('<div id="teste"><div class="form-group col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco" name="Valor[]" value="0.00" /><span class="form-highlight">$</span><span class="form-bar"></span><label class="label1" for="Valor">Valor</label></div><button class="remove_field" style="background-color: #313348;"><span class="fa fa-trash fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>');
      }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#teste").remove();
    x--;
  })
});



$(function() {
  $('.Preco').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-warning caixa add_field_button" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-5x taman" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
     <div class="form-group col-md-2">                      
      <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco" name="Valor[]" value="0.00" required>
       <span class="form-highlight">$</span>                        
       <span class="form-bar"></span>                       
       <label class="label1" for="Valor">Valor</label>        
     </div>
    </div>
```

As I show in the example the first input works correctly, but when I create a dynamic input it lets the maskMoney function work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function() {` and `$(function() {` are the same thing. (This is mentioned in [the jQuery documentation for `.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)) Because of that, you've essentially declared two `onready` handlers. `onready` handlers can happen in any order.

Combine them into one `onready` handler and order the contents such that the call to `maskMoney` happens last.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the document you put here. Can you explain with an example that it is easier to understand?

Comment: You don't really need to understand the document in order to solve the issue. Just understand that there are several ways to write an `onready` handler in jQuery and that you're unnecessarily using two of them when you should be using just one. Simply move the line containing `.maskMoney` to the end of the function passed to `.ready`.